# How to filter multiple patterns using HSCAN / redis

Tags: redis, ioredis

I tried with `ioredis` but HSCAN only supports a single match pattern.

What's the best way to filter multiple patterns from redis

```
var stream = redis.hscanStream('myhash', {
    match: `foo*`,
    count: 10
})

stream.on('data', function(resultKeys) {
    // add 
})

stream.on('end', function() {
    // end
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Lua script for this purpose

Only using val ; i don't need key hence the `if j % 2 == 0`

```
local arr = {}
local len = redis.call('hlen', KEYS[1])
for i=1,#ARGV do
    local match = redis.call('hscan', KEYS[1], 0, 'match', ARGV[i], 'count', len)
    for j=1, #match[2] do
        if j % 2 == 0 then
            table.insert(arr, match[2][j])
        end
    end
end
return arr
```